# jQuery - [ERROR] . after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am displaying a floating menu bar. It's working fine but I'm getting the below compilation errors:

[ERROR] ...\src\main\webapp\resources\js\util\modules\floating-j-menu.js:line 29:column 15:syntax error
 menuPosition=$('#menuJF').position().top + 485;
[ERROR] ...\src\main\webapp\resources\js\util\modules\floating-j-menu.js:line 31:column 1:syntax error
[ERROR] ...\src\main\webapp\resources\js\util\modules\floating-j-menu.js:line 1:column 0:Compilation produced 5 syntax errors.

Please help me see the error here.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  if ($("body").height() > $(window).height() - 41) {    
    $('#menuJF').removeClass('hide');
  }
  menuPosition = $('#menuJF').position().top + 485;
  FloatMenu();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  FloatMenu();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 41) {
    $('#menuJF').addClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#menuJF').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions. This was, frankly, an unreadable mess before I edited it

Comment: Judging by the error it looks like you have some invalid invisible non-breaking space characters in the code which are causing the issue. I'd suggest removing them

Comment: Provide HTML to compare with please.

Comment: HTML code:  <div id="menuJF" class="floatingItems hide">
 <label for="odVideoLabelLink"
  title="<spring:message code="footer.link.odVideo"/>"> <a
  href="${odVideoUrl}" target="new" id="odVideoLabelLink"> 
  <span class="icon-videocam" />
 </a></label>
 <label for="navTop" title="<spring:message code="label.backToTop"/>" class="cc"><a
  href="#"> <span class="icon-up-big" />
 </a></label>
</div>

Comment: Please use the `edit` button under the question to add it

Comment: The HTML code above is broken syntactically. Fix it and then post it. Please refrain from posting broken code as this will discourage people from even attempting to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had syntax errors all over the place.

Some misplaced brackets and so on as you could see in your error `floating-j-menu.js:line 26:column 26:missing ) after argument list`.

Here is your code:

---

```js
if ($("body").height() > $(window).height() - 41) {
  $('#menuJF').removeClass('hide');
}


menuPosition = $('#menuJF').position().top + 485;
//FloatMenu();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  //FloatMenu();
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 41) {
    $('#menuJF').addClass('hide');
  } else {
    $('#menuJF').removeClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
#menuJF {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 1500px;
  background: red;
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuJF">
  this is my menu
</div>
```

---

I also commented out `floatMenu()` function since you haven't provided its functionality.

Comment: function FloatMenu(){
 var animationSpeed=1500;
 var animationEasing='easeOutQuint';
 var scrollAmount=$(document).scrollTop();
 var newPosition=menuPosition+scrollAmount;
 if($(window).height()<$('#menuJF').height()){
  $('#menuJF').css('top',menuPosition);
 } else {
  $('#menuJF').stop().animate({top: newPosition}, animationSpeed, animationEasing);
 }
}

Comment: HTML and CSS too please.

Comment: CSS:  #menuJF {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: -38px;
  top: 0px;
  left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 2px 3px 4px;
  background-color: $grey-e;
  font-size: 22px;
 /* CORNER ROUNDING */
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
 /* BORDER */
  border: 1px solid $brand-color-1;
  border-right: 0px;
  /* NOTE: BORDERs ABOVE ARE | top | right | bottom | left */ 
  a {
    color: $brand-color-1;
    font-size: 22px;
  } 
 }

Comment: While I did ask to include the extra info, please add it into your actual post to give this information to others.

Comment: Yes, due to non-breaking space characters not compiled. now its working fine.  -thanks Alex